# How to integrate wit.ai into website chat window?

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai

There is a handy option in DialogFlow to integrate it into a website without any hassle. Is there any option of the same kind for wit.ai? What are the steps to do so?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have your bot deployed on your website using wit you can actually use their customer webchat (which is like having your messenger deployed on your website) see documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/